# jQuery array value update when being inputted

Tags: jquery, ajax

Currently my function gets activated when the input is clicked but is there a way that I can make it show the alert if the word they have typed in is already there?

**Example:**

If the user types in `homepage` and its already taken (there is PHP involved but im just sorting the AJAX atm) I would like it to show the error - not when the input is clicked.

**Function:**

```
$(".postForm").on('click', '#post_title', function (e) {

    var data = {
        moviesparx_website_id : $('#post_title').data("id"),
        post_title            : $('#post_title').val()

    };

    console.log(data);

    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: '<?=base_url()?>/page/op',
        data:data ,

        type: 'POST',
        success: function (resp) {
            alert(resp);
        },
        error: function (resp) {
            console.log("Error in ajax request");
        }
    });

});
```

}

Comment: You could trigger the ajax call using  on blur or keypresses (on the actual input field)

Comment: @jonosma Can I have an example would I need to change my post_title to "input type etc"?

Comment: Yes, it would be rather similar to what you have now. just changing to .on( "blur", '#youInputFieldId', handler ) or using keypress $( "#youInputFieldId" ).keypress(function( event ).

Comment: Just remember that if you trigger the call on each keypress, you may have quite a bit of extra traffic -> that's why it may be a more efficient to do it on blur.

Comment: @jonosma can you answer the question with onblur and ill mark it answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using onBlur should meet your requirements :)

On blur will work when the user exits the focus of the current input element (http://api.jquery.com/blur/).

Answer (score 0):

Check it in keypress function of the input:

```
$('#theInput').keypress(function(){
if($(this).val()!=''){
// write your ajax checking code here...
}
});
```